# Right to left setting in dynatree

Tags: jquery, dynatree

how to change Right to left setting in

> dynatree ?

```
 <div id="tree" style="text-align:right;"></div>
```

i use text-align but all nodes show in right of page.
like this:
[my tree](http://www.sharefile.ir/uploads/1385410107.jpg)

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: thanks but what's fiddle? how can i create fiddle?

Comment: [**jsFiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/), dont forget to add jquery from `**Frameworks & Extensions**` and dynatree files in `**External Resources**`. Whole code is not required just try to make a small example closer to your problem. After Done click on `save` or `update` and attach the url from `share` or browser address bar in the comment or question

Comment: i find my answer: 
http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found My Answer:

```
 onPostInit: function () {
                // Set RTL attribute on init
                this.$tree.find("ul.dynatree-container").attr("DIR", "RTL").addClass("dynatree-rtl");
            }
```